# I am experiencing trouble with MySQL Update and i don't know how to fix it

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MySQL. Here is my codeblock:

```
public function updateTable($obj, $column_names, $table_name, $bannerid) {

    $c = (array) $obj;
    $id = $bannerid;
    $keys = array_keys($c);
    $columns = '';
    $values = '';
    foreach($column_names as $desired_key){ // Check the obj received. If blank insert blank into the array.
       if(!in_array($desired_key, $keys)) {
            $$desired_key = '';
        }else{
            $$desired_key = $c[$desired_key];
        }
        $columns = $columns.$desired_key.',';
        $values = $values."'".$$desired_key."',";
    }
    //$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name."(".trim($columns,',').") VALUES(".trim($values,',').")";
    //mysql_query("UPDATE blogEntry SET content = '$udcontent', title = '$udtitle' WHERE id = $id");
    $query = "UPDATE ".$table_name." SET "."(".trim($columns,',').") = VALUES(".trim($values,',').")" ."WHERE id = '$id'" ;
    $r = $this->conn->query($query) or die($this->conn->error.__LINE__);

    if ($r) {
        $new_row_id_update = $this->conn->insert_id;
        return $new_row_id_update;
        } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(image_url,intro) = VALUES('800bf5f59a1d13c8.jpg',',sd,cfcjaklewfh ewiuofejkfdh ' at line 1100

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use `insert` syntax to `update`.  It should be like this: `update yourtable set field = val, field2 = val2... where id = val3`

Comment: MySQL has quite good online documentation, the documentation for [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) should make it rather apparent VALUES lists are not involved.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @sgeddes the insert statement is been commented out leaving update. by the way the insert into works very well. thank you.

Comment: @tadman i have already clean the input with javascript from the ui. i appreciate Sir. i'm going through your reference now

Comment: That's a false assumption. You **can not trust** data you receive via `$_GET`, `$_POST` or anything like that. Your JavaScript means nothing to an attacker, they won't even run it. You **must** use prepared statements with placeholder values or, in rare cases where that's not practical, use the proper escaping method. This is a big deal, so play it safe. Tiny mistakes can and will be punished severely by automated hacking tools. Just looking out for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sgeddes is correct about the query structure.  Try this one.  You should echo out the $query to make sure it builds correctly.

```
public function updateTable($obj, $column_names, $table_name, $bannerid) {

    $c = (array) $obj;
    $id = $bannerid;
    $keys = array_keys($c);
   $subquery='';
   foreach($column_names as $desired_key){
       // Check the obj received. If blank insert blank into the array.
   if(!in_array($desired_key, $keys)) {
        $$desired_key = '';
    }else{
        $$desired_key = $c[$desired_key];
    }
    $subquery.=$desired_key."='".$$desired_key ."',";
}
//remove trailing common
$query="UPDATE ".$table_name." SET " substr(subquery,0,-1)." WHERE id = '$id'" ;
$r = $this->conn->query($query) or die($this->conn->error.__LINE__);

   if ($r) {
    $new_row_id_update = $this->conn->insert_id;
    return $new_row_id_update;
    } else {
    return NULL;
   }
```

}

Comment: it didn't work and it truncate some text of the input. herethe result: syntax to use near 'are world class trainin WHERE id = '38'' at line 197

Comment: I see it.  I missed the closing singles quote and comma. Replace $subquery.=$desired_key.'='.$$desired_key;  with  $subquery.=$desired_key.'='.$$desired_key ."', ";  That is a double quote, a single quote a comma a space and then a double quote

Comment: the single had no closing part. could you please explain.i really want to know. meanwhile let me try it out

Comment: I fixed the original code in my answer. I should have done that the first time.  If you echo out the $query, it should come out like this UPDATE the_table SET field1='$value1', field2='$value2' WHERE id=1

Comment: $query="UPDATE ".$table_name." SET ".substr($subquery,0,-1)." WHERE id = '$id'";   its not working. please help. here is the error:                                                           You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '38'' at line 1100. code not working

Comment: I would need to see the actual query.  It is possible that some of your values have single quotes in them which is throwing it all off.

Comment: I have fixed it with rtrim function. The problem with the query was the last comma on the the query before the WHERE CLAUSE. I shall share my code block when am on desktop. Thanks